# Anaconda python prioritized over system python

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I have updated my Debian from 10 to 11, and it was successful. By default, the Python version on Debian 11 is 3.9. However, when I put the command python --version, I got the old version. I checked the question a little bit and I have found that Anaconda's Python version is the like system default (3.7.11) whereas the system version is the 3.9.2

```
raul@rbritto:~$ python --version
Python 3.7.11
```

But when I make the alias command, I got the new version. In my bin folder, I have the python3.9 folder too.

```
raul@rbritto:~$ alias python='/usr/bin/python3.9'
raul@rbritto:~$ python --version
Python 3.9.2
```

```
raul@rbritto:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3602816 Jul 14 05:11 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr  5  2021 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr  5  2021 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.9-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5479736 Feb 28  2021 /usr/bin/python3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Feb 28  2021 /usr/bin/python3.9-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.9-config
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: in debian python should be a symlink to python2. if your python is a symlink to (an old) python3 maybe you haven't updated properly the package `python-is-python3`

Comment: what is the output of `which python` and `echo $PATH`? probably anaconda's python comes first in the `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, I edit the ~/.bashrc file and look to the line with the export statement to PATH.

So I changed the line to the new value:

```
export PATH="/home/user/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/user/anaconda3/bin"
```

Doing this change you modify the precedence in PATH variable